# Can't use paperclip+lightbox together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, lightbox

How to perform this piece of lightbox code using rails link_to method

```
<a href="img/bmw.jpg" data-lightbox="cars" data-title="My caption"><img src="img/bmw.jpg"></a>
```

the image_tag outputs images well

```
image_tag(@ad.photo.url(:medium))
```

so how to use this image_tag with link_to so lightbox works?

my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require lightbox
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

and my application.css is

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
 *= require lightbox
 *= require mystyle
 */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`link_to image_tag(@ad.photo.url(:medium)), @ad.photo.url(:original), data: { lightbox: "cars", title="MyCaption" }`

Breakdown: The first image_tag is your thumbnail, and the second, is your original image which will be shown in the modal generated by lightbox.

Btw: That is Slim syntax.

Working code after debugging:

`link_to image_tag(@ad.photo.url(:medium)), image_path(@ad.photo.url(:medium)), data: { lightbox: "cars", title="MyCaption" }`

Comment: :original is how paperclip is saving the original file . That's just an example, you should tailor your code how you need it now. So instead of `:original` put what you have..

Comment: ok, vlad, now i'm working on it, i think the problem is how i put the css and js files in the assets pipeline

Comment: Vlad, can you see please, i updated my css and js file, is something wrong there?

Comment: `require_tree .` and `require_self` should be last. But I don't think that's your problem. Open your console and see what js errors you get when you try to open lightbox.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: http://localhost:3000/ads/show/car_ads/16/medium/vetton_ru_bmw-6-series_coupe_2012_1600x1200_wallpaper_10_23668.jpg?1432590398

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/ads/show/car_ads/16/medium/vetton_ru_bmw-6-series_coupe_2012_1600x1200_wallpaper_10_23668.jpg?1432590398 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: http://localhost:3000/ads/show/car_ads/16/medium/vetton_ru_bmw-6-series_coupe_2012_1600x1200_wallpaper_10_23668.jpg?1432590398

Comment: actually the images are in root folder/app/assets/images/car_ads

Comment: Well then, your problem is somewhere else. You're probably not using paperclip as you're supposed to. Read their docs maybe, I can't really help you more without seeing more code and how you use it in the the views, how you're uploading etc..

Comment: no, paperclip by itself is working properly, i'm sure about that

Comment: <a data-lightbox="cars" data-title="MyCaption" href="car_ads/16/medium/vetton_ru_bmw-6-series_coupe_2012_1600x1200_wallpaper_10_23668.jpg?1432590398"><img src="/assets/car_ads/16/medium/vetton_ru_bmw-6-series_coupe_2012_1600x1200_wallpaper_10_23668-393480958359a86974461704488109ab0545caad538c9f315a6ddcb854b78534.jpg?1432590398" alt="Vetton ru bmw 6 series coupe 2012 1600x1200 wallpaper 10 23668 393480958359a86974461704488109ab0545caad538c9f315a6ddcb854b78534"></a> that's how a-tag outputs

Comment: <img src="/assets/car_ads/16/medium/vetton_ru_bmw-6-series_coupe_2012_1600x1200_wallpaper_10_23668-393480958359a86974461704488109ab0545caad538c9f315a6ddcb854b78534.jpg?1432590398" alt="Vetton ru bmw 6 series coupe 2012 1600x1200 wallpaper 10 23668 393480958359a86974461704488109ab0545caad538c9f315a6ddcb854b78534"> that's how img-tag outputs, and images shows well

Comment: has_attached_file :photo, :processors => [:watermark],
      :styles => {
       :small=>"140x105",
       :medium=>"1136x851",
       :original => { :geometry => "800>",
           :watermark_path => "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/watermark.png", 
           :position => 'SouthEast'} 
      },
      :url => "car_ads/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
      :path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/car_ads/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

Comment: Looking at them two, I can only see that the `link_to` doesn't give you the `/assets` path. Try this: `link_to image_tag(@ad.photo.url(:medium)), image_path(@ad.photo.url(:medium)), data: { lightbox: "cars", title="MyCaption" }`

Comment: BRAVO VLAD, THAT WORKS )))) THANKS A LOT

Comment: Cool, glad we found the issue! :)